Current operator for Bloch electrons
I'm trying to understand why in some lectures or review (e.g. in QHE lectures by Tong, or in the review Topological Field Theory of Time-Reversal Invariant Insulators by Qi), they say (without a proof) that the current density can be represented by a current operator acting on  Bloch states $|u_{nk}\rangle$, and that is defined by $$\hat{j}_i = \dfrac{e}{\hbar}\dfrac{\partial H(k)}{\partial k^i}.$$ To setup the notation, we note here by $|\psi_{nk}\rangle$ a Bloch state whose wavefunction is $\psi_{nk}(x) = e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}}u_{nk}(x)$, and $|u_{nk}\rangle$ is the state whose wavefunction is $u_{nk}(x)$.The Bloch Hamiltonian in presence of a gauge field is $$H(k) = e^{ikx}H e^{-ikx} = \dfrac{1}{2m}\left(-i\hbar\nabla + \hbar\vec{k}+e\vec{A}\right)^2 + V(x)$$ where $V$ is a periodic potential with the same periodicity as the lattice.
In order to prove this claim, I tried to start from the very definition of a current operator in one body quantum mechanics (as we're working with non interacting Bloch electrons), namely that a current operator is an operator whose diagonal matrix elements satisfy the continuity equation $$\dfrac{\partial n}{\partial t} + \nabla\cdot\vec{j} = 0,$$
where $n = e|\psi(x,t)|^2$ is the charge density, $\psi$ is the state in which we are interested, and $\vec{j} = \langle\hat{{\vec{j}}}\rangle_{\psi}$ is the expectation value of the current operator in state $\psi$. In https://www.phys.ksu.edu/personal/wysin/notes/qmcurrent.pdf, they arrive at the following definition for a current operator $$\hat{\vec{j}}(x,t) = \dfrac{e}{2m}\int dx \left[|x\rangle\langle{x}|\left(\vec{p}+e\vec{A}\right) + \left(\vec{p}+e\vec{A}\right)^\dagger|x\rangle\langle{x}|\right].$$
By evaluating the expectation value of this operator in a Bloch state, one arrives to (if I'm not mistaken) $$\langle\hat{j}\rangle_{u_{nk}}
= \dfrac{e}{m}\int dx \ \left(\hbar\vec{k}|u_{nk}|^2 + \dfrac{ie\hbar}{2m}\left(u_{nk}\nabla u_{nk}^* - u_{nk}^*\nabla u_{nk}\right)+\dfrac{e^2}{m}\vec{A}|u_{nk}|^2\right),$$which, I think, actually makes sens physically. Yet, this doesn't match the definition of the current operator given at the begining of this post, as $$\left\langle\dfrac{e}{\hbar}\dfrac{\partial H(k)}{\partial \vec{k}}\right\rangle_{u_{nk}} = \int dx \ \left(\dfrac{e}{m}\hbar\vec{k}|u_{nk}|^2 - \dfrac{ie\hbar}{m}u_{nk}^*\nabla u_{nk}+\dfrac{e^2}{m}\vec{A}|u_{nk}|^2\right).$$ Even though these two expressions are very close, they are not the same. Maybe I did something wrong, if someone knows what I missed, I would be glad to read you!

EDIT : Following T.P. Ho's comment, I corrected the sign and numerical factor mistakes. Using the fact that $u_{nk}$ is normalized, we can conclude that indeed, these operators have the same matrix elements in a basis of the Hilbert space.

They assume knowledge of solid state physics, from texts like Ashcroft&Mermin. However people coming to fancy field like topological insulators do not always have solid state/condensed matter background'

I dont really get the point of your comment here, I understand the intuitive explanation behind the expression of the current operator as a derivative of the Bloch Hamiltonian, what I am looking for is a proof, starting from the very definition of a current density in quantum mechanics.

This is basic condensed matter / semiconductor theory stuff, covered on books like Ashcroft or landau volume xi. I am suggesting to consult the books.

I am sure OP missed some signs and some factors of 2.  Apart from that, remember $\vert u \vert^2$ is normalized to unity.  So $u^{} \nabla u + u \nabla u^{} = 0$.

Hello, yes that's definitely it. Thank you for your help, that solves the issue! I edited the post to correct the few calculation mistakes.

@Roger V. But there is no vol. XI in Landau&Lifshits. Do you mean vol. IX (Stat. Phys. part 2)?

@John Sorry, my mistake. Anyhow, it is the one where they deal with the solid state. Kittel is another standard reference to check.

Satisfying the current conservation equation is an unsatisfactory way to define the current because it does not provide a unique answer:  you can add any identically conserved current (the curl of something for example) and still have a conserved current.
A better  definition of the current operator is that it is the functional derivative of the action wrt to the gauge field $A_\mu$. It then automatically satisfies the current conservation equation because of gauge invariance $A_\mu \to A_\mu+\partial_\mu \Lambda$. Note that $k_\mu$ and $A_\mu$ appear in the same place in the covaraint derivatives, so differentiating wrt to $k_\mu$ is equivalent to differentiating wrt to $A_\mu$. For the spatial components of the current you can replace the action density  by the hamiltonian, and this is what Tong does.
